# How to alter wordpress media links

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am adding images to WordPress but when I see the links they are like:

```
http://content.domainname.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo.png
```

and it is creating issue, it should be:

```
http://domainname.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo.png
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove the subdomain of links?

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: Via Admin area**

1) Go to Dashboard->setting->General->update urls.

2) Go to Dashboard->setting->General->Paramelink->select default urls.

3) Save setting.

**Case 2: Plugin for database url update :**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/